# Crash on tableview when reloading at index

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    _previewView = previewView
    super.viewDidLoad()
    delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self

    let currentUser = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!
    let currentUserRef =  DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child(currentUser)
    let cutoff = Double((Date().timeIntervalSince1970) - 60 * 4 *  200000000)

    currentUserRef.child("invitedToPosts").queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryStarting(atValue: cutoff).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        let post = snapshot.key
        self.posts.insert(post, at: 0)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = post
    return cell
}
```

The goal of this is to grab a post, get the key of the post, add that key at the front of a postsArray and then reload only that cell.

When I run the app I get the error:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 0 from section 0 which only contains 0 rows before the update'`

Code works fine when I just run `tableview.reloadData()`, but this crashes out.

Any ideas why this is happening/ how to get this to work?

Comment: Where are you deleting row?

Comment: I'm not haha, that's where I'm confused. I've got the above code in my viewDidLoad, numbersOfRowsInSection, and cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Your edited question makes no sense because now your posted code makes no call to `reloadRows(at:)`.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I had just reverted it back to reloadData() in my code until I sort it out and when I copypasted it in for the  edit forgot to change it back to reloadAt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `reloadRows(at:)` should only be used when you actually wish to reload existing rows.

In the code you posted, this is not the case. In your code, you are adding a new row to your data model. So you need to insert a new row into the table view, not reload an existing row.

Replace the line:

```
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

with:

```
self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

Using `reloadData` works because it simply does a complete reload of the table view. It doesn't matter what changes you've made to the data model.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you relaoding a specific row like you did, Be sure you have such a row in tableView.

Here error is of because you're trying to remove a row which is not there in tableView(code not in question).

In case you calling `reloadData()` it will execute all delegates once again.

Answer (score 0):

as RMaddy said, using insertRows works. But if you may even remove some rows, you will need to use reloadRows.

So in that case, what you can do is do a small check if that indexPath exists and then reload/insert accordingly.

Comment: No, if rows are removed (which is not the case in this question), you would use `removeRows(at:)`, not `reloadRows(at:)`.

Comment: What I meant was instead of using a removeRows(at:) and a insertRows(at:), he can just use only a reload with a check right?